# Data validation and list of errors within one message box c#

Tags: c#, messagebox

Hope you all well. I would like to ask you for an advise.

I am looking for a way to validate a data before OnClick button gets executed.
I do have few ComboBoxes with some data to choose from. Currently I have used some solution, which does look quite "dirty" and I am not happy about it.

Currently I am using something similar to this:

```
if(box1 == null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error 1");
}
if(box2 == null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error 2");
}
if(box3 == null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error 3");
}
```

If I am having 3 fields empty I will get message displayed 3 times one for each error. Is there a way to list all errors within one message box if error is true?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
bool a = true;
bool b = true;
bool c = true;

a = (box1 == null);
b = (box2 == null);
c = (box3 == null);

if(a || b || c)
{
  //Display list of errors where condition is true
}
```

I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var errors = new List<string>();
if(box1 == null)
   errors.Add("Error 1");
if(box2 == null)
   errors.Add("Error 2");
if(box3 == null)
   errors.Add("Error 3");

if (errors.Count > 0) 
   MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String builder for this [String builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private object box1;
private object box2;
private object box3;

//The following code base could be in a button click event

StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

if(box1 == null)
{
   errorMessages.AppendLine("Error 1");
}
if(box2 == null)
{
   errorMessages.AppendLine("Error 2");
}
if(box3 == null)
{
   errorMessages.AppendLine("Error 3");
}

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(errorMessages)))
{
    MessageBox.Show(errorMessages.ToString(), "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This will show an empty box if there are no errors.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi Add the check.